# Distance between two places based on longitude and latitude

Tags: python

I have a Python dataframe like attached in the picture:

[image]

where post codes are the actual post codes and their longitude and latitude, I am trying to calculate the distance from postcode_x to postcode_y

[image: dataframe format]

I wrote a Python function:

```
def distance(lat_1,lon_1,lat_2,lon_2):
R = 6373.0
# radius of the Earth


lat1 = math.radians(lat_1)
# coordinates

lon1 = math.radians(lon_1)
lat2 = math.radians(lat_1)
lon2 = math.radians(lon_2)

dlon = lon2 - lon1
# change in coordinates

dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = math.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2)**2
# Haversine formula

c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
distance = R * c
```

This works fine when I call it

```
lat_1 =52.2296756
lon_1 =21.0122287
lat_2 = 52.406374
lon_2 = 16.9251681
distance(lat_1,lon_1,lat_2,lon_2)
Ans is 278.40645089544114
```

however, when I try to feed this in a new column of the `DataFrame`

```
result['distance']=distance(result['LATITUDE_x'],result['LONGITUDE_x'],result['LATITUDE_y'],result['LONGITUDE_y'])
```

it shows the error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> 

 TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-44558335aa06> in <module>
----> 1 result['distance']=distance(result['LATITUDE_x'].astype(np.float),result['LONGITUDE_x'].astype(np.float),result['LATITUDE_y'].astype(np.float),result['LONGITUDE_y'].astype(np.float))
      2 result

<ipython-input-53-4dddb160b896> in distance(lat_1, lon_1, lat_2, lon_2)
      4 
      5 
----> 6     lat1 = math.radians(lat_1)
      7     # coordinates
      8 

c:\python\python 3.95\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    139         if len(self) == 1:
    140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    142 
    143     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I tried:

1. `result['distance']=distance(result['LATITUDE_x'].astype(np.float32),result['LONGITUDE_x'].astype(np.float32),result['LATITUDE_y'].astype(np.float32),result['LONGITUDE_y'].astype(np.float32))`
2. instead of `np.float32`, I put `astype(float)` all are showing same error.

Comment: "it shows the error" - what shows the error? radians? sin? cos? Whatever you used to fill up the indexed object with the 4 coordinates that you aren't showing us? Exception stack trace, please.
Your function body also does not have any indentation. This code would not work, no one can reproduce your problem.

Comment: The coordinates are in the pictures as I am taking value from a table having those columns. I am a new user so a link to the picture is available here(the picture can be pasted by the old user only), I pasted the whole error for the reference

Comment: why do you use the tag python 2.7? - you use python 3.95

Comment: If you're using pandas, can you look at the output of dataframe.dtypes and post it here?

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan Thanks! From your exception trace, it looks like your result[...] objects are Series objects, not floats, and your error occurs when math.radians is trying to convert them to float. I do not know what your Series objects contain, but you should take the desired float element out of the series, and use those as latitude and longitude values. EDIT: I guess they contain the entire column of latitudes and longitudes, don't they? Your distance function only calculates 1 value, so you can try calling it over the cells in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `distance()` function does not support vectorized operations, thus you can't apply it to vectors, only scalars.

In order to solve it, you have two options: apply the function row-wise (perhaps using df.apply()) or to vectorize your function by using numpy (best approach):

```
import numpy as np

def distance(lat_1,lon_1,lat_2,lon_2):
    R = 6373.0
    # radius of the Earth


    lat1 = np.radians(lat_1)
    # coordinates

    lon1 = np.radians(lon_1)
    lat2 = np.radians(lat_1)
    lon2 = np.radians(lon_2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    # change in coordinates

    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2)**2
    # Haversine formula

    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c
    return distance
```